# HttpURLConnection Read time out

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, socket-timeout-exception

I have a following code to download file form URL

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlOfFile.openConnection();
urlConn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);

StatusInfo.fileSizeTobeDownload = urlConn.getContentLength();

InputStream reader = urlConn.getInputStream();

FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(downloadFolder+fileName);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
int bytesRead = 0;  
while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    StatusInfo.fileSizeDownloaded+=bytesRead;
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

This code works fine, but sometime i got following error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:554)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:807)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:94)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
 at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2582)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2577)
```

without any network drop. Is there any other way to configure "ReadTimeout".

Comment: I am not sure but  may be your internet speed is too low, or it may take time to respond

Comment: we have good speed out there, I tried to download it from 3-4 machines simultaneously  and it fails on one machine, and fails on every retry and after some time it was successfully downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense. You set a read timeout, you got a read timeout. If you got it sooner than you expected, set it to be longer. The only 'other way to configure read timeout' you need is to change the timeout value. What that should be, only you know, as only you know why you're setting it. Ten seconds does seem too short to me.

NB you don't need to keep recreating the read buffer. You're just creating tons of garbage.

Comment: I'm running the ping to 8.8.8.8 while testing, without ant drop in ping the error happened to me. 10 sec is a enough duration to see the ping drop. I think I'm getting timeout on very small part of time, in that even ping not failed.

Comment: Ping failing or not failing has nothing to do with it. It has to do with how quickly your server responds. You are only allowing it ten seconds. It's too short,

Answer (score 0):

It means the server is not responsed in ReadTimeout,perhaps the server is closed or the handling thread is blocked or the server is too busy.

Comment: If the 'server is closed' you would not get this exception.